# Search textbox default value - QueryPromptString

Tags: search

I have OOB sharepoint application. This has got the search enabled. I would like to give the default text for the search text box. So, I have given the following code in the Elements.xml file of SmallSearchInputBox Delegatecontrol. But still I dont see any default text in the search box. Please help me to fix this.Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <Control
       Id="SmallSearchInputBox"
       Sequence="10"
       ControlAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
       ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx">
        <Property Name="GoImageUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearch15.png</Property>
        <Property Name="GoImageUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/gosearchrtl15.png</Property>
        <Property Name="GoImageActiveUrl">/_layouts/images/gosearchhover15.png</Property>
        <Property Name="GoImageActiveUrlRTL">/_layouts/images/gosearchrtlhover15.png</Property>
        <Property Name="DropDownMode">ShowDD_NoContextual</Property>
        <Property Name="ScopeDisplayGroupName">Search Dropdown</Property>
        <Property Name="FrameType">None</Property>
        <Property Name="QueryPromptString">Search...</Property>
      </Control>
    </Elements>
```

Comment: Are you deploying this as a feature? Did you activate the feature? What site template are you using? What is the Sequence property value set to? Here's an example of how to override the SmallSearchInputBox delegate control: http://www.blendmaster.net/blog/2012/06/enable-query-suggestions-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Yes, I am deploying as a feature and I have activated that.Sequence Property value is 10.  I am using the standard site template.

Comment: Seems like the issue is related to the ShowDD_NoContextual drop down mode. SharePoint is not using the QueryPromptString property value in that case for some reason.

Comment: What could be problem with the ShowDD_NoContextual. I dont get any error or failure in functionality is happening due to this.

Comment: Could some one help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way achieving your goal is by inserting your default text to search box using JavaScript/JQuery code.

Using JQuery:

```
var textBox = $('#searchBoxID');
textBox.val("Search...");
```

Using JavaScript:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("searchBoxID");
    textBox.value = "Search...";
```